# Solving $y = x \tan\theta + \frac{g x^2}{2v^2\cos^2\theta} $ for $\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Can anyone solve for $\theta$?

$$y = x \tan\theta + \frac{g x^2}{2v^2\cos^2\theta} $$

I've gone to like 3 teachers and I just need $\theta$ in terms of these other variables/constants, but I can't get it into few enough terms to be solvable.

Comment: I don't think there's a nice way to do this.... it may just (actually, almost certainly) not be expressible as a combination of standard functions.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: A reminder that just because a question can be written easily does not mean that the question can be *solved* easily.  Why do you expect there to be a convenient solution for this?  Where did the problem come from?

Comment: $\sec\theta=\frac1{\cos\theta}$. Do you know how $\tan\theta$ and $\sec\theta$ are related? (Generally, the more you can say about what you know, the better. This will help people avoid wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level.)

Comment: Using $\;\sec^2=\frac1{\cos^2x}=1+\tan^2x\;$ , you can turn the equation into a quadratic in $\;\tan\theta\;$ ...but it still will yield a not-so-pretty couple of solutions...

Answer (score 2):

Observe that

$$\sec^2\theta=\frac1{\cos^2\theta}=1+\tan^2\theta$$

so

$$x\tan\theta+\frac{gx^2}{2v^2\cos^2\theta}=x\tan\theta+\frac{gx^2}{2v^2}\left(1+\tan^2\theta\right)\implies$$

our equation is

$$\frac{gx^2}{2v^2}\tan^2\theta+x\tan\theta+\frac{gx^2}{2v^2}-y=0$$

The above is a quadratic in $\;\tan\theta\;$ whose discriminant is

$$\Delta=x^2-4\frac{gx^2}{2v^2}\left(\frac{gx^2}{2v^2}-y\right)$$

and thus

$$\tan\theta_{1,2}=\frac{-x\pm\sqrt\Delta}{2\frac{gx^2}{2v^2}}$$

and then from here to obtain $\;\theta\;$ using $\;\arctan\;$...but still not very pretty.